# Excel macro to compare two ranges for perfect match

Tags: vba, excel

When  I run a macro, I'd like a message to pop up if the values for L6:L29 match, row to row, the values in M6:M29.

The long and inefficient way to write this might be:

```
Public Sub MyMacro()
    If Range("L6").Value = Range("M6).Value 
AND Range("L7").Value = Range("M7).Value 
AND Range("L8").Value = Range("M8).Value 
etc.
    Then
        MsgBox "Both columns match!.", vbInformation, "Match!"
    Exit Sub
End If

...

End Sub
```

But I'm looking for more efficient code that can evaluate each row in the two columns/ranges without having to specify each pair.

I did see the below answer to a similar question, but it evaluates only *one* row (in this case, #5). I need to evaluate every row in the range: [Fastest way to check if two ranges are equal in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270693/fastest-way-to-check-if-two-ranges-are-equal-in-excel-vba)

```
Sub RowCompare()
    Dim ary1() As Variant
    Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, rr1 As Range, rr2 As Range
    Set Range1 = Range("B9:F20")
    Set Range2 = Range("I16:M27")
    Set rr1 = Range1.Rows(5)
    Set rr2 = Range2.Rows(5)
    ary1 = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rr1))
    ary2 = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rr2))
    st1 = Join(ary1, ",")
    st2 = Join(ary2, ",")
    If st1 = st2 Then
        MsgBox "the same"
    Else
        MsgBox "different"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can change that code to do the columns by only using Application.Transpose once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
```

---

```
Sub RowCompare()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim ComparisionResult As Boolean

    For i = 6 To 29
        If IIf(Cells(i, 12).Value = "", "", Cells(i, 12).Value) = IIf(Cells(i, 13).Value = "", "", Cells(i, 13).Value) Then
            ComparisionResult = True
        Else
            ComparisionResult = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

   If ComparisionResult Then MsgBox "Both columns match!", vbInformation, "Match!" Else _
        MsgBox "different", vbInformation, "Match!"

End Sub
```