# How to compare two range of cells in two different excel Worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I've put my vba code here to show you my progress so far on the subject. This is intended to be a macro which activates on a commandbutton click.

Thank you for your suggestions, unfortunately I don't see if that flagged duplicate would solve my problem. I will try to clarify it the best as i can. In each Worksheets, in the same range there are two identical 9*9 width and height block of cells, and each cell is filled with a single number from 1 to 9 value. The values of the cells are identical too in both worksheets. What I would expect from my code to do is to compare the two ranges's each value in each cell, and if all of them are a match, write in msgbox success, else fail. I tried writing .Value after defining each range, but that doesn't work either.

I always get a runtime error 13: type mismatch. I was guessing this type of problem is related to that my values are not the same type, but I only have numbers in each declared range. I've googled the problem, but since i can't seem to figure out the root of this problem, I'm hoping You can be an answer to my dilemma.

```
Sub Check()    
    If Sheets("Sudoku").Range("B2:J10") = Sheets("Solution").Range("B2:J10") Then    
        MsgBox "Success!"
    Else    
        MsgBox "Fail!"    
    End If    
End Sub
```

Any kind of answer would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you all for the answers, We finally came up with a solution! I'll put it below if anyone is interested in it. It is a slightly modified version of Odatas's version.

```
Sub Check()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 2 To Sheets("Sudoku").Cells(Sheets("Sudoku").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To Sheets("Sudoku").Cells(2, Sheets("Sudoku").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If Sheets("Sudoku").Cells(j, i).Value = Sheets("Megoldás").Cells(j, i).Value Then
        Else
            MsgBox ("Fail!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
Next
MsgBox ("Success!")

End Sub
```

Comment: What property of the range are you trying to compare? And what problem arises with your code?  If it is the `.Value` property, you need to check each cell individually.  If it is something else, then clarify your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if two ranges are equal in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270693/fastest-way-to-check-if-two-ranges-are-equal-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through all values.

```
    Sub Check()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer


    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sudoku").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        for j= 1 to Sheets("Sudoku")..Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If Sheets("Sudoku").Cells(j, i).value = Sheets("Solution").Cells(j, i).value Then

            Else If
                MsgBox("Fail")
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Next
    Next

    MsgBox("Success")
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution with slight modifications worked! I'll update the thread according to this, and put the working code in if anyone else wonders how to do it.